# Android not receiving response back from java server

Tags: java, android

I have a android app that connects to my linux server (which has java port listener listening for connections) and when I send a command (for example "uname") it will spit out "linux" on the terminal side (which is intentional since its just temp. to make sure its readable) and when I send it back (assuming it does) android doesn't receive it, or java never sends it off to begin with, here is the client side (android) of the communication code.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        try{
            OutputStream outStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            String message = "uname";
            outStream.write(message.getBytes());
           while(true){
               DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
               byte[] disbyte = new byte[1024];
               dis.read(disbyte);
               String disString = new String(disbyte);

               //temporarily text place holder when server sends output back.
               serveresponse.setText(disString);
           }


        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
```

Here is the server side (Java on linux machine) communication code

```
try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            System.out.println("Listening on Port: "+PORT);
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("New Client has connected");
            while(listening){
                DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                byte[] bread = new byte[1024];
                input.read(bread);
                String instring = new String(bread);

                try {
                    shellprocess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(instring);
                    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(shellprocess.getInputStream()));
                    String s = null;
                    while((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null){
                        OutputStream outStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                        outStream.write(s.getBytes());
                        outStream.flush();

                        //this line is to see if the output is correct in the terminal, just here temporarily
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }

                }catch(Exception e){

                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

My question is how do I send response back (output from shell command) to android client?

Comment: Did you debug it? 
Just because I am curious, why do you use Sockets and not libs that abstract that away?
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077322/core-java/core-java-sockets-programming-in-java-a-tutorial.html

Comment: Sorry for late response late day at work and on a friday. I used sockets cause tbh I thought it was suppose to use sockets.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Well if you want to learn about how to use them, yes they are a good point to start but if you want to develop an app fast look for libs that help you with that because there are so many things that you would have to take care of. 
For Android you could take a look at OKHttp or Spring Rest template. On the serverside spring data rest might be a good choice to effectivly write a service.

Answer (score 0):

The function that communicate with server must be pushed in a Thread or AsyncTask class.

Comment: From server or on android?

Comment: On Android. you can refer at http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-asynctask-example/

Comment: You think that's why it doesn't update the ui? Maybe do it in background and when it receives it put it on post execute?

Comment: you can create an interface class:<br>

Comment: you can create an interface class: `public interface AsyncResult{ void getResult(String res);} ` then `public void onPostExecute(String result){ AsyncResult.getResult(result);}` in MainActivity `public void onClick(View v){new ClassAysnTask(new AsyncResult(){public void getResult(String result){//add result to TextView...}}).execute();}`

Comment: OK I've done async before but I was just being a lazy bum. Async can be a pain. Thanks for the pseudo code.

Comment: Yeah async still did not help, i tried to do public interface, but it just went downhill from there. Thanks for the help, it seems it can't be done.

Comment: it's ok with me. https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=76D85F62397EDE3D!6102&authkey=!ANYQdQlJHsudFHo&ithint=file%2cjava